# Look for a second advisor while on the first, any advice?

Tags: advisor

Due to incompatibility with my current advisor, I am currently looking for other advisor on his back. Any advice? I am so scared that what if he discovers that I'm looking around. Now I have tried to set up new email account so I can deny everything if things get ugly. Any people have the same experience, can you share your trick with me please? It is pretty much a very dangerous covert mission.

Comment: Have you considered having a heart-to-heart talk with your adviser? If the relationship is not working for you, it's likely not working for your adviser either. Not all people are compatible with each other.

Comment: its all too late now as I have made the first "contact" through an email to another advisor today. I just want to know any trick I can be successful in this transition. Thx!

Comment: Are both of them in the same department? If not, do they know each other? What have you mentioned to the prospective advisor?

Comment: "It is pretty much a very dangerous covert mission.". No. it's something that happens all the time.

Comment: See, the problem you look for advisors in the same department is that they can know each other quite well so I wonder how difficult it can be to switch within the same department?

Comment: _Now I have set up new email account so I can deny everything if things get ugly_. That seems a bit over the top. You had a fallout with your advisor – you're not the first. There is potential for hard feelings to hinder your progress – it's time to accept that. I don't think you help yourself by being "covert". Will others be more likely to take you on if you're begging for secrecy and using clandestine email accounts? I don't think so. You want a trick? Try acting like a mature adult, accept that this may not be all your advisor's fault, and recognize you probably have some culpability.

Comment: Sure, I will invite my new advisor and current advisor to a dinner tomorrow.

Comment: @user10694 - Of course you don't go around campus with a bullhorn, and I understand the need to walk on eggshells. But sneaking around too much can backfire on you; it may hint that there is something more sinister than is really there. If I were a potential new advisor, I wouldn't be too keen on taking on a new student who was going through such drastic measures to keep everything hush, so he could **lie** about it later. _I am so scared that what if he discovers that I'm looking around..._ He's going to find out eventually, right? When will you put on your big-boy pants and deal with it?

Comment: _Now I have tried to set up new email account so I can deny everything if things get ugly._ — **Get out.  Get help.**  No matter how bad things are with your current advisor, you will be far better off in the long run being open and honest.  **Of course** anyone you court as your new advisor is going to talk to your old advisor before they agree to work with you.  Your apparent paranoia is going to destroy any chances of a working relationship with anyone.  I sincerely recommend taking a leave of absence and seeking professional counseling.

Comment: It is impossible to openly talk to my advisor, he will deny everything you said like it's all in your mind.

Answer (score 13):

I don't see anything dangerous or necessarily covert about looking for another advisor, and I'm puzzled by things like using a new e-mail account you can deny was yours.  (Are you planning to make contact under a fake name?  Pretend someone was impersonating you if your current advisor finds out?)

You don't need to be nearly so worried.  It's completely reasonable to switch advisors, and I know plenty of people who have done it without any trouble at all.  You don't owe your current advisor anything, and there are no good grounds for anyone to object.

Of course you could cause offense if you are tactless.  Don't tell your advisor "I'm switching because I'd prefer a competent advisor."  But there are plenty of reasonable excuses.  For example, you could say your interests are developing in ways that are a better fit for an advisor with a somewhat different specialization.

Fair or not, your advisor is probably not happy to be working with you either and may actually be relieved when you switch.  In comments on other questions you have expressed a fear that your advisor will badmouth you to other potential advisors.  That's possible, but you could also run into the opposite phenomenon: sometimes an advisor who is frustrated with a student will try to convince other faculty to take on the role of advisor, since then the student will be someone else's problem.  (The less cynical version is that the student may get along better with an advisor with a different personality.)

I'd recommend keeping two things in mind:

1. You seem very interested in criticizing your advisor.  Now is not a good time for that, whether it's addressed to your advisor or to a potential replacement.
2. You seem worried that you are doing something underhanded.  If you act nervous and suspicious, people may suspect you are up to no good.  Looking for a new advisor is not doing anything wrong, and you may get a better reaction if you treat it straightforwardly and calmly.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. Thinking about changing advisor has been on my mind for two years but I just don't have the guts to act on to it until now. I have asked around my friends, family and they just told me all kind of reason not do it. I realized that if I'm not doing it, I'm not learning anything from this lab (my advisor pretty much prevent me from working on any experiment) and I am just wasting my time here. I regret that I joined this lab and should really act on to it sooner.

Answer (score 2):

> Due to incompatibility with my current advisor, I am currently looking for other advisor on his back.

Did you mean "behind his back"? That's okay, people usually don't tell their advisor (or employer, in the business world) when they're looking for another one to switch to.

> Any advice? I am so scared that what if he discovers that I'm looking around.

If he finds out and confronts you about it just tell him that you don't feel like you are able to contribute to the research that he does.

> Now I have tried to set up new email account so I can deny everything if things get ugly. [...] It is pretty much a very dangerous covert mission.

Nope, that's just paranoid.

> Any people have the same experience, can you share your trick with me please?

I switched, after a year with my first advisor. The work he was having me do didn't interest me at all, and to be honest, I wasn't doing it as well as I probably could (lack of motivation reduces work quality).

I simply asked about the department for who was looking for graduate students (like I did in the first year to find this advisor in the first place). I didn't tell my current advisor, but I also didn't take any paranoid measures like switching email accounts. I used my official university account for everything. After finding a new advisor, he contacted the old advisor, making sure everyone is good with the switching arrangement, I finished up my semester of work (up to the end of the contract of the funded project) with the old advisor, I had a meeting where I gave an overview of the work to the person who will take it over and answered some questions, and then I started working with the new advisor.

At the end, everyone was fine. I'm even collaborating with the old advisor a little on some research right now.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to have a single supervisor than two. Because every time you show some work, there will be two advices and many revisions to your papers,thesis.

Unless you know the professors thoroughly, don't consider having two supervisors.

Comment: I think this is a much too simplistic answer to a complicated issue: getting twice as much advice and twice as much revisions sounds like a good thing rather than a bad thing, but there are drawbacks to have more than one advisor.  My first PhD student had a second advisor, and although it made things *more complicated for him* at times, I think that overall it worked out very well for him.  Anyway, I think the OP is contemplating **switching** advisors, not getting another one.

Comment: I agree with Pete regarding advantages, but only when 2 advisors are compatible with each other. Getting advise from both of them will be very helpful in research but this slows you down when their thinking angle diverges.